# Library I need fails in Xam on Ventura. So now I need to move to Forms or MAUI? Or not?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui

All,

I’ve been working on a project for a few years. When I started, forms didn’t have all the features I needed, so I stuck with Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac, and all the business code is shared (C#). It’s taken a lot longer to complete than expected, but I have been going through the final acceptance tests with external testers. In other words... I'm *close*!

However I’ve run into a snag. A library that I rely on *heavily* (lets call it libXYZ) has stopped supporting Xamarin.Mac (they do support .Net Core). That didn’t matter for a while, everything still worked. I talked to their devs, and they said it should keep working.

Well, after the upgrade to Ventura, everything went bad. Something changed catastrophically, and the Mac version no longer runs due to some weird failures in libXYZ. I’ve worked with one of their developers on it, but there’s not much he can do because Xamarin.Mac is no longer supported. Xam.iOS still works.

So I have a large body of code in Xam.Mac and Xam.iOS for the UI, and a large body of business logic, all in C#.

My choices seem to be:

1. Replace libXYZ. This will be a big task. There are some alternatives that I have reviewed, and one of them looks like it will offer what I need (although a significant amount of testing and redesign will be required first). This probably implies staying with Xam.
2. Switch to Xamarin forms which will be a complete rewrite of the UI. A core UI requirement is for a good rich text editor (like {NS,UI}TextView), and SyncFusion has a decent cross-platform RichText editor that works in forms.
3. Switch to MAUI, which will be a complete rewrite of the UI, but will get me support for windows/android more quickly. Unfortunately MAUI is missing any rich text editing, and SyncFusion has no date for when their RichText component for MAUI will be ready.

My concern is Forms is going to EoL because MS is pushing MAUI hard, and if I switch to forms, I might as well go to MAUI. But MAUI seems a little undercooked at the moment,  building a large complex UI in XAML seems complicated, and it lacks Rich Text.

Lastly, MS have already announced that Xamarin will EoL next year. So staying with Xam seems problematic in the short term.

I’ve been staring at this decision for a few weeks now, and would appreciate any advice and/or input. Is there something I'm missing?

Many thanks
P

Comment: Should not need to rewrite UI. Can use your iOS native UI on Mac, via MacCatalyst. I’ve never tried that, but it is what I would try first. In vs 2022, do you see an “ios app” template? Make a project, see if that mentions maccatalyst. If not, Make a Maui project, but don’t use the cross- platform UI. I’m not sure how to do that. May need to post an issue at “github maui issues”, asking how to support ios and maccatalyst, using ios native ui.

Comment: You can upgrade from Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac to .Net for iOS and .Net for MacOS without converting your UI to MAUI. There are a few breaking changes, but the migration should be straightforward compared to migrating to Forms. .Net for iOS is part of the MAUI workload in VS for Mac. .Net for MacOS (Cocoa) is a separate workload. Whether the authors of libXYZ need to update their library will depend on what it does and if it has any platform dependencies.

Comment: @toolmakersteve - having a single app for IOS and mac via Mac Catalyst would be ideal. I will investigate doing that. I had a quick look, and couldn't find examples of converting existing Xam.iOS apps to Catalyst, but it looks like I can create a catalyst app, then move my files into that project (replacing appdelegate, etc). I will experiment. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT - do you know of any examples of this migration, other than (as far as I can see) creating a new project, then copying my files across and fixing what breaks? Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: I have created a Xam.Mac app and modified it (added a few controls). Then I created a .Net for MacOS app (using .Net 7). Then I copied all .cs, .designer and .storyboard files from Xam *over* the .Net for MacOS project files. A couple of minor fixes later (fix namespaces, change the ViewController constructors) and the app runs! So this is promising, at least for a small test.

Comment: Just an update on this... I upgraded my Xam.Mac and Xam.iOS code to .Net for Mac and .Net for iOS. These were relatively small upgrades with just a few days of fixes. Now I am effectively on .net core and the library XYZ works and is supported (although their latest release broke for ventura, and then broke the fix for iOS - sigh).